# Post-apoc YA novel with a focus on pre-war totems

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

I remember reading this in the late 90's; it was a YA novel and most of the characters were fairly young. The story was set a few generations after a nuclear war destroyed civilization and focuses on a band of young tribe members. Each tribe member gets a totem and our lead character gets a particularly valuable one, a pre-war chronograph.

During the course of the story the group find a pre-war underground bunker/base that is still functioning autonomously. It causes a lot of consternation as to whether it's right to pillage it for weapons and equipment but in the end they group decide to do so. As they go to leave, one of the youngest members has a burst of enthusiasm and runs for the entrance, which the bases automatic defences interpret as a threat and promptly gun the kid down. The group then decided that the old tech is cursed and bury the base once and for all.

I couldn't swear to it, but I think the story was actually set in the UK rather than the US and it may have been part of a series. No idea as to author or title.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 3):

Could this be *[Riddley Walker](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/776573)* by Russell Hoban?

> In the far distant future, the country laid waste by nuclear holocaust, twelve-year-old Riddley Walker tells his story in a language as fractured as the world in which he lives. As Riddley steps outside the confines of his small world, he finds himself caught up in intrigue and a frantic quest for power, desperately trying to make sense of things.

Various [reviews](https://www.catherine-fearns.com/10-books-that-made-me-evil-scarecrows-alice-babylon/) mention 'totems'

> With the breakdown of society, literacy is non-existent. In Riddley’s
> world, oral tradition is how stories are passed on, and fragments of
> the old civilisation are treated like holy totems of mystical power
> that can only be loosely (and usually incorrectly) interpreted.
> Hoban’s ability to play with language is enviably clever, as he
> reveals over and over the fluidity and multiplicity of meaning. It’s
> not an easy read, because it’s written in an entirely made-up
> language, but it’s so worth the effort. Also, side note: Clutch wrote
> a song about it.

Comment: No; I'm afraid not. The book was aimed at a high-school aged audience and the writing/spoken style was fairly standard; further the group dynamics were important and I think this book if focused on a single protagonist. Thanks for new read though!

Comment: @J.Doe - *[The Girl Who Owned a City](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Girl_Who_Owned_a_City)* was my other guess

Comment: Not that one either (lead character was male, no underground bunker complexes in this story and published to early)